# Как установить Django в виртуальной среде в Windows 7 из локальной папки на компьютере?

Tags: python

При установке Django в виртуальную среду Python 3.7 (Windows 7) пакет качается из интернета. Но иногда бывает, что нет доступа к интернету. И если, например, установочный пакет находится в папке С:\python_works\Django-2.2.5.tar.gz на компьютере, можно ли установить Django в виртуальную среду Python 3.7 из этой папки и как это сделать, если можно? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Распаковать архив, перейти в каталог django-master, выполнить `python setup.py install`. Удалить каталог и архив за ненадобностью.

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось.